# Excel When Drop down box selected auto fill other boxes

Tags: excel, combobox, autofill

I have an excel spreadsheet that has drop down comboboxes on sheet 1. I am trying to find out how to autofill the 5 boxes to the left of the combobox with content from sheet 2 when a specific drop down is selected.

Comment: Which ever one works really... I have got the data validation and form/active x to drop down my options but I cannot get either to associate other boxes with the drop down selected. IE I pick "Option 1" and then the cells directly to the left fill with the information from sheet 2 about option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use VBA. Where you first put value from sheet 2:

```
With Sheet2.ComboBox1
    .AddItem A1
    .AddItem A2
    .AddItem A3
End With
```

And then you set ListFillRange in sheet 1: A1, A2, A3

Here is some example: [link](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/combo-box.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with out a macro, just select the form element, click the developer tab and then click properties. Then select Control in the form that appears.:

[image]

**This results in:**

[image]

Comment: I can get the drop down okay it would be when the drop down is selected how do I get the data associated with the specific item selected to show up in the same sheet? IE in your picture if you select "Januar" then in the I3,F3, .... columns information specific to "Januar" auto fills.

Comment: In the first image, you can see an option to fill named "cell link". This outputs the value of the drop down box into a cell. You can then just refer to this cell in all the other cells. (for example: cell F3 has the formula "=$K3$K")